# What is your experience with AlertLogic?

Tags: network, ids

Do you have any insight, or experience (good or bad) regarding AlertLogic?

In what areas can they improve, what areas are they lagging in?

Comment: closed - this is a very subjective question so any answers you do get are likely to be opinions, and with no activity so far I'm not sure anyone here has experience of it.

Comment: reopened - agree with AviD - worth leaving it a while to see if anyone does pitch up with info on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for a company that is partnered with AlertLogic. My experience so far has been mixed. I think they have a really solid product that can provide a real security benefit to their customers.

My negative experience has to do with an installation for a client of ours. They required some information from us so that they could configure the devices before hand and ship them out, ready to be installed. One of the devices still had its default configuration and wasn't setup for the network. The process of dealing with them and trying to get things figured out took a lot longer than it should have. They were also apprehensive about giving us access to the devices ourselves. Once we had access, however, we were able to figure out the problem in a matter of minutes.

They are still a relatively new company and I'm customer service situations like the one I had will improve.